# Java heap size error in mirth

Tags: java, mirth

I am using mirth connect 3.0.3 and i am having a .xml file which is almost 85mb size and contains some device information. i need to read this .xml file and insert that data to the database(sql server).

the problem i am facing is when i try to read the data it is showing java heap size error:
i increased server memory to 1024mb and client memory to 1024mb.
but it is showing the same error. if i increase the memory to more, i am not able to start mirth connect.

any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Use a profiler like VisualVM to see what's in your heap, and work out whether it's your code's fault or Mirth's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the XML file comprised of multiple separate sections/pieces of data that would make sense to split up into multiple channel messages? If so, consider using a Batch Adapter. The XML data type has options to split based on element/tag name, the node depth/level, or an XPath query. All of those options currently still require the message to read into memory in its entirety, but it will still be more memory-efficient than reading the entire XML document in as a single message.

You can also use a JavaScript batch script, in which case you're given a Java BufferedReader, and can use the script to read through the file and return a message at a time. In this case, you will *not* have to read the entire file into memory.

Are there large blobs of data in the message that don't need to be manipulated in a transformer? Like, embedded images, etc? If so, consider using an Attachment Handler. That way you can extract that data and store it once, rather than having it copied and stored multiple times throughout the message lifecycle (for Raw / Transformed / Encoded / etc.).